# How to handle db application related errors and exception in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, compiler-errors, error-logging, error-log

Question: 46234035.

There is a function blurb_stream()
in which I am calling a function message (Which I have drop/ doesn't exist)
Hence in order to catch that error I have given exception block in blurb_stream():

```
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN 
    v_state   = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
    v_msg1     = MESSAGE_TEXT,
    v_detail  = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
    v_hint    = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
    v_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;


 raise notice E'Got exception:
            state  : %
            message: %
            detail : %
            hint   : %
            context: %', v_state, v_msg1, v_detail, v_hint, v_context;
```

But instead of raising these errors, it is reflecting in console:

```
ERROR:  function mobile.message(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT mobile.message(v_status)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT mobile.message(v_status)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function mobile.blurb_stream(jsonb) line 190 at assignment
********** Error **********

ERROR: function mobile.message(integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function mobile.blurb_stream(jsonb) line 190 at assignment
```

Kindly help to proceed.

Comment: please post code of `blurb_stream` - otherwise we can't tell why exception is not caught